# How set my website iis application pool setting in web config?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How set my website IIS application pool setting in web config?
Is this possible?
I want set this settings:
[image: I want set this settings:]

Comment: You Can Do it programmatically with Powershelll, if relevant for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Choosing the application pool for your application is a "Setup" issue, rather than a "configuration".